# max(count) oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate, aggregate-functions

I want to select the employee who has signed most contracts in the last 3 months:
The connections between tables are: contracts.responsible references employees(id)

```
select b.name, b.id, count(*) nr_contracts_last_3_mths
    from contracts a join employees b
    on a.responsible = b.id and   
    data between add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MM'), -1) and trunc(sysdate)
    group by b.name, b.id
    having count(*) = 
      (select max(count(responsible)) 
            from contracts, employees
              where contracts.responsible = employees.id
              group by employees.name
        );
```

The result is contains only the empty selected columns (no data).

The expected result should have **the name of the responible**, **his id**, and value **5** since the bellow query returns 5;

```
select max(count(*)) nr_contracts_last_3_mths from contracts where data 
       between add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MM'), -3) and trunc(sysdate)
       group by data;
```

Comment: It would helpful if you provide sample and desired output data.

Comment: in your subquery `having count(*) = ...` you get the `max` regardless the time period. may that is your problem....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select b.name, b.id, count(*) nr_contracts_last_3_mths
    from contracts a join employees b
    on a.responsible = b.id and   
    data between add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MM'), -3) and trunc(sysdate)
    group by b.name, b.id
    having count(*) = 
      (select max(count(*)) 
        from contracts a join employees b
           on a.responsible = b.id and 
           data between add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MM'), -3) and trunc(sysdate)
           group by b.name, b.id
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query doesn't work because the subquery in the `having` clause doesn't have the condition on the timeframe, so it returns a higher count than any of the rows in the "top" query (as, presumably, employees have also signed contracts before the last three months).

Regardless, a much easier approach would be to use the windowing `rank` function in conjunction with your "top" query:

```
SELECT name, id, nr_contracts_last_3_mths
FROM   (SELECT   b.name AS name, 
                 b.id AS id,
                 COUNT(*) AS nr_contracts_last_3_mths
                 RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS rk
        FROM     contracts a
        JOIN     employees b ON a.responsible = b.id AND
                                data BETWEEN 
                                     add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MM'), -1) AND 
                                     TRUNC(sysdate)
        GROUP BY b.name, b.id)
WHERE  rk = 1
```